# Problems installing scikit-learn on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, scikit-learn

I installed scikit-learn via:

```
 sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev python-setuptools \
                     python-numpy python-scipy \
                     libatlas-dev libatlas3gf-base

sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib

sudo apt-get install python-sklearn
```

When testing with `nosetests -v sklearn`
I first got 3 errors
such as `ERROR: sklearn.datasets.tests.test_lfw.test_load_fake_lfw_people`

I then followed the suggestion to use Neurodebian from thread [1808](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/1808)

now `nosetests -v sklearn`
fails right away with

Failure: OSError (No such file /home/username/MachineLearn/sklearn) ... ERROR

and when I test for versions of joblib and sklearn I get:

```
 Installed: 0.5.4-1
  Candidate: 0.8.2+git7-g0211f4c-1~nd12.04+1
  Version table:
     0.8.2+git7-g0211f4c-1~nd12.04+1 0
        500 http://neurodeb.pirsquared.org/ precise/main amd64 Packages
 *** 0.5.4-1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

apt-cache policy python-sklearn
python-sklearn:
  Installed: 0.14.1-1~nd12.04+1
  Candidate: 0.14.1-1~nd12.04+1
  Version table:
 *** 0.14.1-1~nd12.04+1 0
        500 http://neurodeb.pirsquared.org/ precise/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.10.0-1build1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: install via [miniconda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html).  Really easy.  Easy to update too.

Comment: I am new to Ubuntu. What do I do after download _Miniconda-3.6.0-Linux-x86_64.sh_ ?

Comment: I solved it with the help of http://askubuntu.com/questions/282350/bash-install-sh-permission-denied-installing-intel-fortran-2011